# How to read SSM Parameter dynamically from Lambda Environment variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-ssm

I am keeping the application endpoint in SSM parameter store and able to access from Lambda environment .

```
Resources:
M4IAcarsScheduler:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Properties:
Handler: not.used.in.provided.runtime
Runtime: provided
CodeUri: target/function.zip
MemorySize: 512
Timeout: 900
FunctionName: Sample
Environment:
Variables:
SamplePath: !Ref sample1path
SampleId: !Ref sample1pathid



Parameters:
sample1path:
Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
Description: Select existing security group for lambda function from Parameter Store
Default: /sample/path
sample1pathid:
Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
Description: Select existing security group for lambda function from Parameter Store
Default: /sample/id
```

My issue is while I am updating the SSM parameter, the Lambda Env. is not update dynamically, and every time I need to restart.

Is there any way I can handle it dynamically, meaning that when it changes in SSM parameter Store, it'll reflect without restart of Lambda?

Answer (score 3):

By using SSM parameters in a CloudFormation stack, the parameters get resolved *when the CloudFormation stack is deployed*.  If the value in SSM subsequently changes, there is nothing to update the lambda, so the lambda will still have the value that was pulled from SSM at the moment the CloudFormation stack deployed.  The lambda will not even know that the parameter came from SSM; rather, it will only know that there there is a static environment variable configured.

Instead, to use SSM Parameters in your lambda you should change your lambda code so that it fetches the parameter *from inside the code*.  [This AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/sharing-secrets-with-aws-lambda-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/) shows a Python lambda example of how to fetch the parameters from the lambda code (when the lambda runs):

```
import os, traceback, json, configparser, boto3
from aws_xray_sdk.core import patch_all
patch_all()

# Initialize boto3 client at global scope for connection reuse
client = boto3.client('ssm')
env = os.environ['ENV']
app_config_path = os.environ['APP_CONFIG_PATH']
full_config_path = '/' + env + '/' + app_config_path
# Initialize app at global scope for reuse across invocations
app = None

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, config):
        """
        Construct new MyApp with configuration
        :param config: application configuration
        """
        self.config = config

    def get_config(self):
        return self.config

def load_config(ssm_parameter_path):
    """
    Load configparser from config stored in SSM Parameter Store
    :param ssm_parameter_path: Path to app config in SSM Parameter Store
    :return: ConfigParser holding loaded config
    """
    configuration = configparser.ConfigParser()
    try:
        # Get all parameters for this app
        param_details = client.get_parameters_by_path(
            Path=ssm_parameter_path,
            Recursive=False,
            WithDecryption=True
        )

        # Loop through the returned parameters and populate the ConfigParser
        if 'Parameters' in param_details and len(param_details.get('Parameters')) > 0:
            for param in param_details.get('Parameters'):
                param_path_array = param.get('Name').split("/")
                section_position = len(param_path_array) - 1
                section_name = param_path_array[section_position]
                config_values = json.loads(param.get('Value'))
                config_dict = {section_name: config_values}
                print("Found configuration: " + str(config_dict))
                configuration.read_dict(config_dict)

    except:
        print("Encountered an error loading config from SSM.")
        traceback.print_exc()
    finally:
        return configuration

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    global app
    # Initialize app if it doesn't yet exist
    if app is None:
        print("Loading config and creating new MyApp...")
        config = load_config(full_config_path)
        app = MyApp(config)

    return "MyApp config is " + str(app.get_config()._sections)
```

Here is [a post](https://alienattack.workshop.aws/en/short-labs/lambda/100-write-to-ssm.html) with an example in Node, and similar examples exist for other languages too.

```
// parameter expected by SSM.getParameter
var parameter = {
    "Name" : "/systems/"+event.Name+"/config"
};
responseFromSSM = await SSM.getParameter(parameter).promise();
console.log('SUCCESS');
console.log(responseFromSSM);
var value = responseFromSSM.Parameter.Value;
```